# How to export content as a doc file from a text area?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 text areas on my website. before_text and after_text

I want to add 'download as doc file' button to area of after_text.

Could you please provide me with the appropriate JS and html code to do so?

I have been searching for it for days but no results.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Build an anchor whose `href` is a data url. Something like:

```
<a href="data:application/msword,HereGoesTheTextAreaContentsBlablabla">Click here to download as a Word document</a>
```

When you click on it, the browser will recognize it as MS Word content, and will ask the user to download it (or the default action for this kind of content).